# Set class variable based on string

Tags: ruby

I am trying to set a value to a variable whose name is given as a string. What is the best way to do this? The first way I thought of was to do if conditions, like:

```
if attribute_string = 'code'
  @code = val
elsif attribute_string = 'weight'
  @weight = val
...
```

But that's ugly and seems like poor coding style. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) How is class variable relevant to your question? (2) Your `if` condition is always true, and will always execute the first part. The whole conditioning does not make sense.

Comment: Please explain your problem in non-programming terms first, that will help both you and us to understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get/set an instance variable from its name by using [`Object#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

```
attribute_name = "code"
val = "value"
instance_variable_set :"@#{attribute_name}", val

# Retrieve value with instance_variable_get
instance_variable_get :"@#{attribute_name}" # => "value"
```

Comment: Note, if the variable comes from user input, this could be used to alter instance variables other than the ones you intend.  You would at least need to run your attribute name through a whitelist.   Alternately, consider storing the data in a hash to keep the namespace contained.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [instance_variable_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) to set an instance variable based on a string. The following example would output `5`:

```rb
attribute_string = 'code'
instance_variable_set("@#{attribute_string}", 5)
puts @code
```